# Check if file exist with Try/Catch

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch

I'm new to this about Try/Catch. In the code below I have a simple test to check if a file exist. In my task for my C# lesson I must use Try/Catch, and I'm not sure how to use this, should I still use the if statement inside the Try part or is there a better way to do the checking if a file exist inside Try? Is there any difference if the file is a simple txt file or a serialized file?

```
if (File.Exists("TextFile1.txt"))
{
   MessageBox.Show("The file don't exist!", "Problems!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

The Try/Catch way I must use

```
try
{
code to check if file exist here
}
catch
{
error message here
}
```

Comment: File.Exists will not throw any exception so I don't think there is really any need of try catch there. You could use some better example for try-catch use.

Comment: you probably want to check if the file is missing then show the message box. Maybe try if (!File.Exists)

Comment: If at all possible, stay away from try-catch, unless you're expecting an exception, and you know how to handle it, or you want to catch any exception to log it and not let it end up crashing your application.

Comment: OT: Actually it is "The file doesn't exist.", however if this is shown to a user as the messagebox implies it is better not to use abbreviations. Therefore it is nicer to say: "The file does not exist." No offence intended btw.

Comment: A try catch is hundreds of times more expensive than just an IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already check on the presence of file in your first sniplet. There is no any need, for *this* code to be inside `try/catch` block.

Comment: Well, there's still a race condition if they want to use the file after the check ;-)

Comment: OK, but I must use Try/Catch or Using in my task when open and save files. I guess the teacher wants us to handle situations if file isn't exists or use has no writing permission

Comment: @3D-kreativ: in *this* code you already check on presence. **May be** you teacher means other: if you immagine, you're writing data to a file on (say) USB drive. A big file. During the write you pull out USB from PC. That means that in the middle of write operation the file becomes no more available (it doesn't exist more), and you have to handle those kind of problems. If you want to check just ones on presenc of file, use File.Exists(..), but if you're going to write something in file, use try/catch for the reasons I wrote before.

Answer (score 11):

```
try
{
 if (!File.Exists("TextFile1.txt"))
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
   // your message here.
}
```

Comment: I know this is what OP asked for but there ought to a disclaimer why this is a terrible idea and an anti-pattern

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
try
{
   if(!File.Exist("FilePath"))
       throw new FileNotFoundException();

   //The reste of the code
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The file is not found in the specified location");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: catch specific exception.. :D

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check if the file exists without using `File.Exist`, then you may try opening the file in a try block, and then catching the exception [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx).

```
try
{
    // Read in non-existent file.
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt"))
    {
    reader.Read();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The file don't exist!", "Problems!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    // Write error.
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I try your code I get a red line below Streamreader, I guess there must be some more code to declare this?!

Comment: Just right click on it and click resolve, or on the top include `using System.IO;`

Comment: I'm using string file = openFileDialog1.FileName; When I'm using the "file" I get the hole path, is there a way to just get the name of the file?

Comment: use `var onlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);`

Comment: Hmm, when I use your last code and when I used the "file" I got a message that the file didn't exist, but that wasn't mine! And When I use your last code, files that exists catch my error message!?

Comment: Reading the entire file into memory just to check if exists seems like a bad idea to me

Answer (score 2):

Use [`throw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx):

```
try
{
    if (!File.Exists("TextFile1.txt"))
        throw (new Exception("The file don't exist!"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Your logic does the exact opposite of what your exception states.

Comment: You forgot the exclamation `!`

Answer (score 0):

You only use a try/catch, when you have an unexpected error, or you are "expecting" an error from accessing a resource. That sounds a bit confusing, but in your cause, there is neither.

If however you opened as stream to READ a file without checking if it exists, that will then be necessary to have a try..catch.

All in all, try..catch's should be applied for safety, and where code is complex/length.

Answer (score 0):

Related to this question following thread will be interesting

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithcsharp/thread/1eb71a80-c59c-4146-aeb6-fefd69f4b4bb

File.Exists API was changed in window 8 and explaination is:

> Currently the only way to check if a file exists is to catch the FileNotFoundException. As has been pointed out having an explicit check and the opening is a race condition and as such I don't expect there to be any file exists API's added. I believe the File IO team (I'm not on that team so I don't know for sure but this is what I've heard) is considering having this API return null instead of throwing if the file doesn't exist.

**Approach with File.Exists is not thread safe and it was removed from API in windows 8. So just catch FileNotFoundException**